Who's this actor?

Having no clue where to go, all I know is that this actor might have played sci-fi roles, but then again, I'm clueless to who he is.

And which trivia game did this one come from?

It wasn't any trivia game, it's from a wallpaper that had multiple things from multiple sci-fi shows.
It's this: Big quotes of"Live Long and Prosper" - Han Solo, with a picture of Nathan and a background from Battlestar Galactica.

That is Nathan Fillion.  The screen shot seems to be from his role of Captain Malcolm Reynolds from the show Firefly.
He has played other roles, including a starring role in the show Castle, and the cult favorite Dr. Horrible's Sing-Along Blog.

That's Nathan Fillion. Best known from Castle and Firefly.
